# Problems ActiveRecord::Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using the gem "Devise" where the model I have called "Center", I created a model "Book" then the judgment.

```
rails g model Book title:string author:string description:text standard_number:integer pages:integer publisher:string year_published:integer
```

Then for associations, I have done so.

models/center.rb

```
class Center < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :registerable, :omniauthable
end
```

models/book.rb

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :center
end
```

My idea is that a center (library) publishes books that are available.

Error: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/de052aefaa63cc7fcf3e

Comment: You've got a `has_many` so you want `a = Center.first` then `a.books`

Comment: Nope, it must be because they believe "center_id" in the model? Error: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c087519848f50d447290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have center_id in your books table.
If you want to call `books` through association there must be a reference key (foreign key) in your child model.

child element always have `parent_id`. Without this you can't find parent/child.

Also when you create book. then try add it with association.

```
@center = Center.find(params[:id])
@book = @center.books.create(book_params)
```

This way rails automatically update center_id in books.

Comment: Good spot, I missed that bit.